# Preventing PDF file to be modified

Tags: ios, pdf-generation

My app generates a PDF from HTML using UIWebview and UIViewPrintFormatter then getting pdf data from UIGraphicPDFContext.

All works well, but I want to prevent pdf file to be modified.
Do you have an idea how to achieve this?

Thanks a lot.

Thierry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to set an owner password and pdf will be signed with.

```
NSDictionary *pdfInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"password", kCGPDFContextOwnerPassword, [NSNumber numberWithInt:128], kCGPDFContextEncryptionKeyLength, nil];
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData( pdfData, kPdfPageRect, pdfInfo );
```

Answer (score 1):

When using `UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData` you can supply a `documentInfo` dictionary which contains keys such as `kCGPDFContextAllowsCopying` and `kCGPDFContextAllowsPrinting` (`CFBoolean` values).

Comment: I think this will not prevent file to be modified using Adobe Acrobat on a desktop machine.